# Using random in Python

Tags: python, random

I am using Python to generate some data and have some code like this

```
num = 0
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        num = random.randint(0,7)
        #some code here
```

Instead of producing random numbers, it just makes ten random numbers, and then repeats the sequence for the next nine sets (eg. [1,2,5,1,0,0], [1,2,5,1,0,0], ...).  When I run this code again later in the program, it will give me a new set of 6 random numbers, but then repeat it for the next nine sets.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You aren't showing enough of your code.

Comment: The reference to ten numbers doesn't make a lot of sense with the code you have shown. More code is generally better, especially if you're assigning `num` into a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop initializing your nested lists incorrectly. `[[...] * n]` is **wrong** and will give you multiple references to the same list. Use `[[...] for x in range(n)]` instead.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed you figured this out without me even showing that part of my code, this fixes the problem.